# How to access docker container localhost

Tags: docker, docker-compose, localhost

I executed docker-compose up and my services worked as well but unfortunately when i hit the url " http://localhost:3000 " it gives me an error I'll paste the docker-compose.yml here.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: psql
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_DATABASE}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./postgresql/conf:/etc/postgresql/
    restart: always
    ports:
     - '5432:5432'
  api:
    build: .
    container_name: api
    restart: always
    command: yarn start
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/app
volumes:
  postgres:
```

When I get into the container and execute `curl localhost:3000` it works fine.

Comment: the '' error '' that i face says  the page that im looking for is not  available

Comment: What is the error you got? knowing the error will help addressing your issue.

Comment: Is this a Python based api (i.e flask or any other)? If yes, can you share the wsgi or uwsgi bind mapping?

Comment: is a node based api. The error when i hit localhost:3000 is a ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved after I changed the host in my node api to '0.0.0.0' it was 'localhost' so I think the application was running only inside the container and after that change it was visible from all the created network.